# SQLite, Select for messages thread

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table like:

**Messages Table:**

```
id | message_text | sender_name | time
```

I previously would also have a `Threads` table which I would query separately. I want to do away with the `Threads` table completely, since all it did was hold the last message received.

I want to return 1 row for each sender_name where the time is the greatest for that sender_name. How can I accomplish this?
Note, I would like to use `SELECT *` to get all the rows

For example, if I have this data:

```
sender_name | time

  bob | 0
  bob | 1
  bob | 30

  tim | 15
  tim | 18
  tim | 20

julie | 7
julie | 12
julie | 25
```

Then from my query, I want to get:

```
  bob | 30
  tim | 20
julie | 25
```

I also need to get the other columns that go with that name and time.

Comment: This is a basic `group by` query.  You should learn SQL if you want to use it effectively.

Comment: `group by` didn't work since that returns the last inserted row (if I'm not mistaken). I try coupling it with an `order by`, but it still returned the last inserted row, not the row with the greatest `time`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT sender_name, MAX(time) time
FROM table
GROUP BY sender_name
```

With SELECT * may be (untested of course)

```
SELECT *
FROM table
GROUP BY sender_name
HAVING time = MAX(time)
```

Not sure if this will work though.

Comment: I updated my question, but I want to use `SELECT *`.

Comment: If you have few columns, what about adding the columns?

Comment: That is an option if I have to do it that way, but I don't want to list the columns in the query

Comment: Check my suggestion on my answer (if it does not work, then, inform me, so I'll remove it)

Comment: I wasn't aware of `HAVING` until now due to never properly/fully learning SQL, but the `HAVING` clause did it. Thanks.

Comment: `HAVING` is like `WHERE` but allows aggregated functions (`MAX`, `MIN`, etcetera). It requires a `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

you can get max time entry in a subquery and then get all columns for that time for each sender

```
select * from tableA A
inner join
( 
select sender_name, max(time) as time
from tableA
group by sender_name
)T
on A.time = T.time
and A.sender_name = T.sender_name
```